# Shell script: segregate multiple files

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix

I have this in my local directory ~/Report:

```
Rep_{ReportType}_{Date}_{Seq}.csv

Rep_0001_20150102_0.csv
Rep_0001_20150102_1.csv
Rep_0102_20150102_0.csv
Rep_0503_20150102_0.csv
Rep_0503_20150102_0.csv
```

Using shell-script,

1. How do I get multiple files from a local directory with a fixed batch size?
2. How do I segregate/group the files together by report type (0001 files are grouped together, 0102 grouped together, 0503 grouped together, etc.)

I will generate a sequence file (using forqlift) for EACH group/report type. The output would be Report0001.seq, Report0102.seq, Report0503.seq (3 sequence files). In which I will save to a different directory.

Note: In sequence files, the key is the filename of csv (Rep_0001_20150102.csv), and the value is the content of the file. It is stored as [String, BytesWritable].

This is my code:

```
1  reportTypes=(0001 0102 8902)
2
3  # collect all files matching expression into an array
4  filesWithDir=(~/Report/Rep_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-1].csv)
5
6  # take only the first hundred
7  filesWithDir =( "${filesWithDir[@]:0:100}" )
8
9  # files="${filesWithDir[@]##*/}" #### commented out since forqlift cannot create sequence file without the path/to/file
10 # echo ${files[@]}
11
12 shopt -s nullglob
13
14 # Line 21 is commented out since it has a bug. It collects files in
15 # current directory when it should be filtering the "files array" created
16 # in line 7
17
18
19 for i in ${reportTypes[@]}; do
20   printf -v val '%04d' "$i"
21   # files=("Rep_${val}_"*.csv) 
     # solution to BUG: (filter files array)
     groupFiles=( $( for j in ${filesWithDir[@]} ; do echo $j ; done | grep ${val} ) )
22
23   # Generate sequence file for EACH Report Type
24   forqlift create --file="Report${val}.seq" "${groupFiles[@]}"
25 done
```

(Note: The sequence file output should be in current directory, not in ~/Report)

Comment: Ideally, one StackOverflow question should have exactly one underlying question. Putting multiple questions into a post risks close as "too broad".

Comment: BTW, `\d` is a PCRE ("Perl-Compatible Regular Expression") extension; UNIX tools typically only support BRE ("Basic Regular Expression") or ERE ("Extended Regular Expression") syntax.

Comment: Per clarification added in a second question, I've amended my answer to use forqlift for creating Hadoop sequence files.

Comment: Question should be clarified to describe how the two actions (taking only the first hundred files, and collating by type) are supposed to interact. Do we collate only the first hundred files in the directory, such that any report type not represented within that 100 files gets ignored entirely? Split into 100-file groups *after* collation?

Comment: If no files are matched by the pattern, by the way, it would be a good starting point to tune the pattern. For instance, to test the first block of `[0-9]`s, replace everything after it with a `*`, and see if that matches any files. If it does, put the next block in, etc., and continue until it *stops* matching content; then, you'll know where the error is.

Comment: There only being 10 possible ReportTypes is an important detail -- I was assuming that all 1000 possible values could be used.

Comment: If there's only going to be 100 files in that directory at a time anyhow, why enforce that limit in your script?

Comment: Get the first 100 files then ignore the rest. since after processing, i am moving the 100 files processed, and then run the script again to process the next 100 (since there's also a script moving files into the ~/Report directory. . . So the step is after collecting the first 100 files (sorted by date if possible so it would be FIFO), we group it per ReportType (there's only 10 ReportType values). Sequence file will then be generated for each ReportType processed. So in this example, there would be 3 sequence file generated.

Comment: Because at some point there would be thousands of files in the directory. (peak) so im doing it by batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to take only a subset of an array:

```
# collect all files matching expression into an array
files=( ~/Report/Rep_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv )

# take only the first hundred
files=( "${files[@]:0:100}" )
```

The second part is trickier: Bash has associative arrays ("maps"), but the only legal values which can be stored in arrays are strings -- not other arrays -- so you can't store a list of filenames as a value associated with a single entry (without serializing the array to and from a string -- a moderately tricky thing to do safely, since file paths in UNIX can contain any character other than NUL, newlines included).

It's better, then, to just generate the array as you need it.

```
shopt -s nullglob # allow a glob to expand to zero arguments
for ((i=1; i<=1000; i++)); do
  printf -v val '%04d' "$i"     # pad digits: 12 -> 0012
  files=( "Rep_${val}_"*.csv )  # collect files that match

  ## emit NUL-separated list of files, if any were found
  #(( ${#files[@]} )) && printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" >"Reports.$val.txt"

  # Create a sequence file with forqlift
  forqlift create --file="Reports-${val}.seq" "${files[@]}"

done
```

---

If you really don't want to do that, then we can put something together that uses namevars for redirection:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This only works with bash 4.3
re='^REP_([[:digit:]]{4})_[[:digit:]]{8}.csv$'
counter=0
for f in *; do
  [[ $f =~ $re ]] || continue            # skip files not matching regex
  if ((++counter > 100)); then break; fi # stop after 100 files
  group=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}               # retrieve first regex group
  declare -g -a "array${group}"          # declare an array
  declare -n group_arr="array${group}"   # redirect group_arr to that array
  group_arr+=( "$f" )                    # append to the array
done

for varname in "${!array@}"; do
  declare -n group_arr="$varname"

  ## NUL-delimited form
  #printf '%s\0' "${group_arr[@]}" \
  #  >"collection${varname#array}"        # write to files named collection0001, etc.

  # forqlift sequence file form
  forqlift create --file="Reports-${varname#array}.seq" "${group_arr[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Heh, heh, heh... I had forgotten about indexed splitting on elements. Thanks again Charles.

Comment: hi Charles, thanks for your continuous answers. I edited my post to show the updated code. the sequence file generated is the combination of all 100 csv files, but I want to group it per Report Type. I am expecting 3 seqfiles. I'm not sure why there is a for loop 1000 in your code, but I am getting blank lines upon "echo ${files}"

Comment: `echo ${files}` will only show the first file (though it shouldn't be blank, unless `i` refers to a ReportType for which no reports exist). `echo "${files[@]}"` should show the complete contents of the array.  With respect to the `for` loop -- it's iterating through possible ReportType values, since your original question indicated that they would be four-digit integers from 1 through 1000. Thus, for any report type where no reports exist, the array will be empty.

Comment: That said, maybe the question was unclear. Is the 100-file limit for a single type, or global? If it's for a single type, do you want to ignore the remaining files, or create a second sequence file for them?

Comment: Sorry Charles, I got the for loop now. Multiple sequence file was generated as expected. But, since there's only 10 report types (0001, 0102, 0503, ..., 8902), I'm thinking if I should replace the loop.

Comment: Yes -- it'd be more efficient to use `for i in 0001 0102 0503 ...; do` instead, since you know the types.

Comment: Hi Charles, btw when I "echo ${files[@]}" after the first line (collect all files), it includes the directory of the files (~/Report). So it doesn't match anything in the "files=( "Rep_${val}_"*.csv )" for loop line. The workaround I used is to execute the script in the same directory of the Report data. But now I'm going to read from a remote server.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148714/shell-script-read-files-from-remote/

Comment: @sophie, if you want to remove the leading directory from all elements of the array, `files=( "${files##*/[@]}" )` will do the trick.

Comment: Hi Charles, upon investigating, I found other major bugs. I updated the code to show this. In the for loop, it's getting all the files* in the current directory (not in ~/Report).

Comment: In line 21, I think we should collect the files in files array defined in line 9 instead. I don't know if this is possible?

Comment: Some of your changes aren't necessary. `declare -g`, for instance, is default behavior when outside the scope of a function. Back to your question -- when the line invoking `forqlift` refers to `"${group_arr[@]}"`, that's informed by the immediately prior `declare -n` redirecting `group_arr` to point at the previously-declared array... so, in fact, it _does_ do what you ask already.

Comment: I did not change anything actually, I'm using your first solution, since I am getting an error in the 2nd solution: "-bash: declare: -g: invalid option. declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]" . . . In the first solution, there's a bug in line 21. Since it is getting the files in the current directory instead of filtering the files array collected in line 9.

Comment: I managed to make it work (updated code) in line 21. I just have to replace the ~/Report to read from a remote host

Comment: @sophie, which version of bash? You need a very new one (4.3) for namevars (`declare -n`).

Comment: bash --version: GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13). btw, do you have any solution for reading remote files without having to use scp/rsync?

Comment: First -- install a newer bash with macports, and start your script with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to use the first interpreter from the environment. Second -- yes, but that needs to be asked as its own question.

Answer (score 1):

I would move away from shell scripts and start to look towards perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %groups; 
while ( my $filename = glob ( "~/Reports/Rep_*.csv" ) ) {
     my ( $group, $id ) = ( $filename =~ m,/Rep_(\d{4})_(\d{8})\.csv$, ); 
     next unless $group; #undefined means it didn't match;

     #anything past 100 in a group is discarded:
     if ( @{$groups{$group}} < 100 ) { 
         push ( @{$groups{$group}}, $filename ); 
     }
}

foreach my $group ( keys %groups ) { 
   print "$group contains:\n";
   print join ("\n", @{$groups{$group});
}
```

Comment: As much as I'm not a fan of Perl, using a non-shell language is arguably the best choice here, inasmuch as bash's native data structures aren't powerful enough implement this as-specified (barring hackery such as using a different variable name per group... which, to be implemented cleanly and safely, would require namevars from bash 4.3, which isn't widely deployed yet).

Comment: It's a tool for a job. I started using Perl from bash when there's some things that are just too difficult to write cleanly. I use perl more and more, because it's able to do most things. It _can_ get very messy, but it doesn't _have_ to. One of the biggest criticisms is people write shoddy code :)

Comment: I don't want to get into a language war here, but I'd argue that some languages make it easier to write shoddy code than others. Given the choice between TIMTOWTDI as a philosophy and a language which -- however flexible -- comes with a strong set of idioms and best practices, my own choice is to prefer the latter. Anyhow -- your code here is indeed very clean and easy to read, even for someone who hasn't touched Perl in a decade and a half (since being hired to maintain someone else's perl, and then getting assigned to make the interpreter cross-compile to a non-self-hosting embedded target).

Comment: (Now, if the question is why in the world I haunt the bash tag if I'm a fond of languages with strong sets of idiom that support clarity, I can come up with no answer beyond sheer perversity).

Comment: No, that's very true. One of perl's strengths is it lets you get away with a lot of stuff. That's also one of it's biggest disadvantages. I'll quite happily get in an argument with someone who's 'showing off' by writing compact gibberish code, that's not easy for someone else to read/understand, because it doesn't matter _how_ clever it is :)

Comment: Note of clarification -- apparently when the OP asked how to create a "sequence file", they were referring to a file format specific to Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to clobber some bash commands together with regexp.
See implementation below

```
# Explanation:
# ls -p = List all files and directories in local directory by path
# grep -v / = ignore subdirectories
# grep "^Rep_\d{4}_\d{8}\.csv$" = Look for files matching your regexp
# tail -100 = get 100 results
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v / | grep "^Rep_\d{4}_\d{8}\.csv$" | tail -100);
    do echo $file;

    # Use reg exp to extract the desired sequence
    re="^Rep_([[:digit:]]{4})_([[:digit:]]{8}).csv$";
    if [[ $name =~ $re ]]; then
        sequence = ${BASH_REMATCH[1};
        # Didn't end up using date, but in case you want it
        # date = ${BASH_REMATCH[2]};

        # Just in case the sequence file doesn't exist
        if [ ! -f "$sequence" ] ; then
            touch "$sequence"
        fi

        # Output/Concat your filename to the sequence file, which you can
        # read in later to do whatever administrative tasks you wish to do    
        # to them
        echo "$file" >> "$sequence"
    fi

done;
```

Comment: It'd be more efficient to only open the `sequence` file once, rather than re-opening it for append every time you want to write another line of output.

Comment: Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- if you want to use grep on filenames, it's safer to `printf '%s\0' * | grep --null`. Similarly, `for file in $(...)` is inherently broken; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor. Safer to use `while IFS= read -r -d '' file` with a NUL-delimited stream as given by the above.