# Shell script: read files from remote

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix

Using shell-script,

How do I read files from another server (user@192.168.10.x:/home/admin/data) and store it in "files" array? (4th line of code)

```
1  reportTypes=(0001 0102 8902)
2
3  # collect all files matching expression into an array
4  files=(Rep_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-1].csv)
5
6  # take only the first hundred
7  files=( "${files[@]:0:100}" )
8
9  shopt -s nullglob # allow a glob to expand to zero arguments
10
11 # echo ${files[@]}
12
13 for i in ${reportTypes[@]}; do
14   printf -v val '%04d' "$i"
15   groupFiles=( $( for j in ${files[@]} ; do echo $j ; done | grep ${val} ) )
16
17   # Generate sequence file for EACH Report Type
18   forqlift create --file="Report${val}.seq" "${groupFiles[@]}"
19 done
```

---

EDIT:

I tried replacing line 4 with:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  files+=( "$file" )
done < <(ssh user@host "cd /home/admin/data && printf '%s\0' Rep_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-1].csv")
```

but when I am to generate hadoop sequence file (using forqlift, line 18), it fails.

```
ERROR  forqlift.ui.Driver - java.io.FileNotFoundException: Rep_0001_20150102_0.csv (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: And what is your question? `cat` is certainly wrong if you want the names of the matching files rather than the contents of the matching files.

Comment: My question is how to read files from another server. My script is only working if I place it in the same directory where my data is.

Comment: BTW -- as a rule, you should quote expansions. `"${reportTypes[@]}"`, not bare `${reportTypes[@]}`. Doesn't actively cause bugs in this specific case unless IFS is set to a value that includes digits found in the values, but better to be in habits that won't cause extra room for bugs ever.

Answer (score 3):

So rewriting this answer now that some of the ambiguities of the question has been cleared up.

You want to copy files, matching a pattern, from a remote host to localhost, then iterate them. Then use scp (or rsync), to download them, then iterate them locally afterwards.

```
# this copies the matching filenames from the remote host to the current dir. The quotes are important.
scp "user@host:/home/admin/data/Rep_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-1].csv" ./

# Now that the files are accessible locally, you may iterate them with a for-loop
for file in Rep_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-1].csv; do
    printf 'Do something with %s\n' "$file"
done
```

Comment: My question is how to read files from another server. My script is only working if I place it in the same directory where my data is. In line 4, I'm thinking of doing "files=(ssh user@host:path/to/files/Rep_[0-9]...")" but it's not working.

Comment: @sophie "read files from another server" is ambiguous. Do you want file **names** or  file **content**?

Comment: This question is a follow-on to two other questions, and knowing their content, my take is that you've interpreted it correctly -- though you might want to clear `files` rather than appending to it for each `val`, since each call to `forqlift` should include only filenames associated with the immediately given `val`.

Comment: @geirha i want both, since i am generating a hadoop sequence file (line 18, which requires the filename as key and content as value). i want what line 4 does, only in remote. I tried your code but it fails on line 18 (please see edited code).

Comment: @sophie, ok, so use rsync to copy them from the remote host, then iterate them.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, now I change my answer to a working script:

```
declare -a ARRAY

count=0;
for F in $(ssh localhost find ./ -name "\*.sh" | xargs basename -a) ; do
  ARRAY[$count]=$F
  ((count++))
done

ELEMENTS=${#ARRAY[@]}

for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
    echo ${ARRAY[${i}]}
done
```

The files you are searching for (in this script *.sh) will be saved into the bash array named ARRAY.

This one is tested, and it works.

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~$ ./filenames2array.sh 
user@localhosts password: 
deleteme1.sh
deleteme9.sh
deleteme2.sh
deleteme7.sh
deleteme8.sh
deleteme10.sh
deleteme4.sh
deleteme3.sh
deleteme5.sh
filenames2array.sh
deleteme6.sh
user@user-virtual-machine:~$
```

This one is written to connect to localhost via SSH. You can change the localhost to whatever remote server you want.

Comment: Every line of that script is wrong. Have you tried it yourself?